# iPhone App Orientation a.k.a. "supportedInterfaceOrientations" line getting "WARNING" Message, even though orientation works perfectly on my iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Here is the line of code I'm using for my landscape-only game:**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
}
```

**My iOS Game was created with Objective-c. I am getting this warning message when using the code above for orientation of the game:**

"Conflicting return type in implementation of 'supportedInterfaceOrientations': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')"

**The game itself works perfectly and responds to both landscape modes, I'm just concerned about the warning message.**

I'm not sure if I should be worried about this or not, I'm fairly new to developing so this might be an obvious fix to some of you, please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature does not match the `UIViewController` API. Change the return type of the method to `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```